# about string.c_str() life cycle

Tags: c++, string

I wonder if the `void func(const char *str);` refer to a valid `str` if I wrote as follow:

```
auto str = string("hello").c_str();
func(str);
```

How is it different from code below?

```
func(string("hello").c_str())
```

Comment: Do you mean `func(str);`?

Comment: Do you mean `func("hello");`? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Paragraph 12.2/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. [...]

This means that the temporary created within the expression that contains the call to `func()` will live until function call returns.

On the other hand, the lifetime of the temporary in the first code snippet will end up before `func()` is invoked, and `str` will be dangling. This will result in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 8):

In both cases, the `string` object is a temporary, destroyed at the end of the statement.

In the first case, `str` ends up dangling - pointing to memory that was managed by the temporary `string`, but which has now been destroyed. Doing anything with it is an error, giving undefined behaviour.

In the second case, the temporary `string` is not destroyed until after the function returns. So this is fine, as long as the function doesn't keep hold of the pointer for something else to use later.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the possibility of the function holding on to a pointer for later use.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that the first creates a temporary `string` object that gets destroyed at the end of the first statement, so `str` becomes a dangling pointer. The second also creates a temporary, but it exists throughout the call to `func` because the temporary object doesn't get destroyed until after the call to `func` returns.

Comment: Good spotting. Yes, the temporary will get destroyed at the end of the first statement because the call to c_str() effectively means str is a const char* and is not a reference to a string object (assuming string is the same as std::string)